# GoogleFit DataReadResult always TIMEOUT

Tags: android, google-fit

when I invoke below code ：

```
Fitness.HistoryApi.readData(client, dataReadRequest).await(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

always get the result :

```
DataReadResult{status=Status{statusCode=TIMEOUT, resolution=null}, dataSets=[], buckets=[]}
```

I don't understand the TIMEOUT means ,and how to resolve the problem .someone can help me ?
thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

It means that one second is not enough time for the request to be served.

See https://developers.google.com/android/guides/tasks for details on how to use Tasks asynchronously.